# Rebuild Query before execution

Tags: java, sql, scala, jooq

I'm researching to use jOOQ with as the abstraction layer to the configurable JDBC backends. One and the required option is the very-specific-database, which supports JDBC, but it has the not-common SQL dialect. I need to work with this database, but I want to keep using the common DSL and API. I'm interested in use of the **DSLContext.executeUpdate** call, for example.
I understand how to solve half of my problems with implementing **DefaultExecuteListener**. But there is another half, there I must translate one statement, generated by jOOQ to another statement, accepted by DB. I think this task should be easier to implement through operating with DSL, than SQL modification.
Is it possible to access the DSL construction inside the ExecutionListener early steps ('start' for example), decompose it and inject the new DSL construction to the consequent steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI, which is also documented here in the manual:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-sql-transformation/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. VisitListener seems to be right point of injection. I promise that I'll take care about performance of the implementation. :) At least to avoid asking questions like "why the jOOQ such slow?" ;)

Comment: @Stinger.911: Well, you do want to do advanced things, so there's a price to pay. And also: Yes. Be very careful for your `VisitListener` to kick in only when it is needed / applicable.